# How to load custom image dataset to X_train

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have to GAN model trained on mnist dataset, I have to train it with my another images dataset

```
(X_train, _), _ = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

how to to the same for images saved in file path?
Here is the kaggle notebook on which i'm working on
https://www.kaggle.com/qbasit/vr-final

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be general to any type of dataset for images. if the format of your image directory is like this:

```
Data...
       Images...
                 Apple class folder
                 Orange class folder
                 Mango class folder
```

If there are folder names with classes of the images and then the folder contains the images in it. then you can use this code to upload the images to your X and classes to y variables.

**First of all set a variable to the dictionary of your class names:**

```
classes = {'Apple':0,'Orange':1,'Mango':2}
```

**then copy path like this:**

```
APPLE_DIR='Images/fruits/Apple'
ORANGE_DIR='Images/fruits/Orange'
MANGO_DIR='Images/fruits/Mango'
```

**After this use this code to make data:**

```
def assign_label(img,fruit_type):
    return fruit_type

X = []
y = []

def make_data(fruit_type,DIR):
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(DIR)):
        label=assign_label(img,fruit_type)
        path = os.path.join(DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT))
        
        X.append(np.array(img))
        y.append(str(label))
```

***If above function gives an error when running code below use try-except in that function like this:***

```
def make_data(fruit_type,DIR):
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(DIR)):
        try:
            label=assign_label(img,fruit_type)
            path = os.path.join(DIR,img)
            img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_WIDTH,IMAGE_HEIGHT))
        except:
            pass;
        X.append(np.array(img))
        y.append(str(label))
```

**Then to run the function use this code:**

```
make_data(classes.get('Apple'), APPLE_DIR)
make_data(classes.get('Orange'), ORANGE_DIR)
make_data(classes.get('Mango'), MANGO_DIR)
```

**All the images with classes will be stored in X and y.
You can view the shape of those Images by following:**

```
len(X)
X = np.array(X)
X = X/255
X.shape //returns the shape (numberofImages,WIDTH,HEIGHT,CHANNELS)
```

libraries used are:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from random import shuffle  
from zipfile import ZipFile
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

This will solve your problem with any custom dataset for images.

Comment: Thanks @Sarim let me try this hope it will work

Comment: Yes sure do try it and let me know if any problem occurs.

Comment: Using `except: pass` like that will cause `X` to occasionally contain strings and `y` to contain the label of a previous image.

Comment: Yes, but i prefer not to use try-except if error is not occuring. If there is a error use it and inside except append X and y with 0 values